# Should I be concerned about the size of a hole and notch in my joist?

Tags: joists, hole, rewire

We've just had the house re-wired (UK), and were wondering whether a hole and notch the electricians have made will significantly weaken the joist?

It is the end joist in the room.

Joist dimentions are 175mm height, 45mm width/thickness and 3350mm length (assuming it is length of room).

Hole has an 80mm diameter.
Notch is 70mm in height (some wood still together in middle).

What would be our best course of action to ensure nothing happens (if it will)?

Thanks

[image: Picture of joist and hole/notch]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You probably should be concerned, but what's underneath the joist? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hi thanks, the room below this is the living room. This is at the end of the house so behind the joist pictured is an end wall.
I checked a few websites and I believe the hole should have been no bigger than 1/3rd of the joist, and the notch 1/6th.

Comment: Yeah, that big notch is almost halfway through the joist, which is (or should be) verboten code-wise.

Comment: Yeah, is just below half the height of the joist. Do you think this would be something remidied with extra support such as an additional piece of supporting wood attached along the side whole joist or steel plates over notch and or hole? Cheers

Comment: Were permits pulled and will this job be inspected? If so make sure you point this out to the inspectors.  You might want to run it by the electricians too.

Comment: 175/70 is 2.5, and you're not supposed to have more than a third removed.

Comment: Cheers all. I've found the relevant docs from our local building control and obviously these are both fairly significant breaches. I will get in touch with our electricans tomorrow about the issue and  also get the wheels in motion to get it inspected and fixed.

Comment: If you discover a good solution, please add it here as an answer. That way future visitors will benefit. Thanks!

Comment: Is that joist sitting directly on another wall? If so it will be fine I am amazed they drilled proper holes on the inner joist but such a large one on that one, but if supported by a wall it will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, the abused floor joist still looks straight. If it happens to be sitting on a foundation/basement wall, it shouldn't be an issue. If it is not supported underneath, it would be a good idea to place a post under it. I wouldn't let the same electrician work on the house anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, holes are usually OK, and notches are not. Notches are like ripping the edge of a piece of paper, which creates a weak point for potential fractures. As noted, the notch on the far right is nearly halfway through the beam, which means you'll have to sister it to repair it (assuming it can be done at all, might want to consult an engineer).

The other notches and holes look decent. The notches on the left are on top, small,  and will likely be secured by the subfloor (I would insist on a 3"/76mm screw on either side of the notch when the subfloor is installed)

If you want peace of mind about the big hole, add a joining/mending metal plate above and below (cheaper to do it now)

Comment: What is a “joining/mending metal plate”?

Comment: @LeeSam Search "joining mending plate" - it's a piece of metal with screw holes drilled in it that you can screw to the joist to reinforce it.

Comment: It would probably be enough to cut the notch a bit wider and a bit cleaner (time to get out the Fein), and then cut a piece of wood *very slightly* longer than the gap, and hammer it in.